# No need to Round off

Tags: asp.net

How can I get??

If my answer is 1.1

then output should be 1.1 (Actual)

My code :-

```
decimal totalUnusedAmount = 0;
decimal.TryParse(txtTotalUnusedAmount.Text, out totalUnusedAmount);

lblAmountDue.Text = ((totalUnusedAmount * Convert.ToDecimal(ViewState["FundedAmount"])) / 100).ToString();
```

but from the above code, getting answer `1.10`. When I debug the code, at the time of debugging it gives 1.1.

Comment: Displaying `1.10` instead of `1.1` is not a "round-off" issue, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this....its working

```
lblAmountDue.Text = ((totalUnusedAmount * Convert.ToDecimal(ViewState["FundedAmount"])) / 100).ToString("0.##");
```

http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify a format to display the number in:

```
lblAmountDue.Text = ((totalUnusedAmount * Convert.ToDecimal(ViewState["FundedAmount"])) / 100).ToString("0.0");
```

Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx

If you are encountering a rounding error, you'll need to use a decimal literal for your `100`. Try this:

```
lblAmountDue.Text = ((totalUnusedAmount * Convert.ToDecimal(ViewState["FundedAmount"])) / 100M).ToString("0.0");
```

The `M` on the end of the number tells the compiler it should be interpreted as a decimal not an `Int32` which is the default literal type for numbers with no decimal places.

Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75(v=vs.110).aspx

To display as the exact answer how you see it in the debugger, you want the "Round-trip" option:

```
lblAmountDue.Text = ((totalUnusedAmount * Convert.ToDecimal(ViewState["FundedAmount"])) / 100M).ToString("R");
```

Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx (at the bottom of the table)

Comment: but if my answer is 1.32 then output should be 1.32 not 1.1

Comment: Ok, see if the edit in my answer helps =]

Comment: this works but I dont wnt round off...I wnt actual answer only

Comment: Ok well instead of `.ToString("0.0")` use `.ToString("R")`. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: hey.....still not working :(

Comment: got the answer .ToString("0.##")

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
lblAmountDue.Text = ((totalUnusedAmount * Convert.ToDecimal(ViewState["FundedAmount"])) / 100).ToString("G29");`
```

Just note that this displays in powers of e if figures are too long.

**Edit**
Works for me

```
decimal tmp = 1.2000000000000M;
Response.Write(tmp.ToString("G29"));
```

Comment: zero answer is coming :(

Comment: Something else might be wrong.